# Keycloak: Send AdminEvent from custom Endpoint (SPI)

Tags: java, keycloak

I have a `Keycloak` extension (Custom Endpoints, SPI). Now I want to add sending of `AdminEvents`, which I implemented as follows:

```
    private void logAdminEvent(ClientConnection clientConnection, UserRepresentation rep, OperationType operation, ResourceType resource) {
    RealmModel realm = session.getContext().getRealm();
    // beware: clientConnection must not be null because of missing check for NullPointer in Keycloak
    ClientModel client = realm.getClientByClientId(ROLE_ATTRIBUTE_CLIENT);
    AdminAuth adminAuth = new AdminAuth(realm, authResult.getToken(), authResult.getUser(), client);
    AdminEventBuilder adminEvent = new AdminEventBuilder(realm, adminAuth, session, clientConnection);
    adminEvent
            .operation(operation)
            .resource(resource)
            .authIpAddress(authResult.getSession().getIpAddress())
            .authClient(client)
            .resourcePath(session.getContext().getUri())
            .representation(rep);

    adminEvent
            .success();
}
```

I am aware that the admin `event` logging must be activated in Keycloak admin console, which I did.

Maybe it is relevant that the logged in user has no administration privileges, but it also did not work when I gave admin privileges.

**I need Ideas or Hints** to what I am **doing wrong here**. Documentation and web research unfortunately did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we found that. 
First, for `update` / `delete`, we had to add the realm to the `adminEvent`. 
Second, for create, we had the `event` logging after the

```
session.getTransactionManager().commit();
```

took place. Setting commit after the `adminEvent.success()` fixed the Issue.

**Maybe this can help anyone.**

Answer (score 1):

**Take a look at Keycloak sources**, especially something like `RootAdminResource`. As far as i remember all admin resources (e.g. `controllers`) create `events` via `builder` that cloned from `builder` that was injected via constructor by parent resource. You may be missing some initialization tricks.

Comment: Thanks. I did have a look and it is as you remembered. By now I did not found the point of failure.

Comment: Ok, we found that. First, for update / delete, we had to add the realm to the adminEvent. Second, for create, we had the event logging after the session.getTransactionManager().commit(); took place. Setting commit after the adminEvent.success() fixed the Issue.